# Block Memory on Machxo 2280C always reads Zeros

Tags: verilog, fpga

So I needed a couple of kB of SRAM on my timing generator project. Since it was not working, I decided to write a dedicated program with a bunch of delays an output word for my logic analyzer to capture (directly connected to the Q of the RAM_DP block and in frustration I've wired it up as below:
[My RAM_DP block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQsmt.png)

I've tried holding write enable high for some mS or even just one cycle(verified by disconnecting my output array and tying a bit to the signal and watching it with the logic analyzer, which pulses as expected). I have also verified the data to write is non-zero.

No matter what I do, Q always remains zero, what am I doing wrong? Must be something pretty obvious for me to miss it. Code below:

```
Ram_Dq_Buffer Buffer  (sram_address,sram_address,s_write_data,s_writeEnable,osc_clck, 1'b1,1'b0,osc_clck, 1'b1,s_read_data ) ;
```

always @(posedge osc_clk )
begin

```
    if (sram_state==0)
        begin
            //Initialize
            s_writeEnable<=0;   
            //sram_Clock_EN <=1;
            //sram_reset <=0;
            sram_address<=511;
            delay<=0;
            sram_state<=1;
            counter<=counter+1;
            s_write_data<=counter;
        end
    if (sram_state==1)
        begin
            delay<=delay+1;
            if (delay>20000)
                begin
                    delay<=0;
                    sram_state<=2;                      
                end
        end
    if (sram_state==2)
        begin
            s_writeEnable<=1;
            delay<=delay+1;
            if (delay>20000)
                begin
                    delay<=0;
                    sram_state<=3;
                    
                end
            
        end
    if (sram_state==3)
        begin
            s_writeEnable<=0;
            delay<=delay+1;
            if (delay>20000)
                begin
                    delay<=0;
                    sram_state<=4;
                    
                end
        end
    if (sram_state==4)
        begin
            delay<=delay+1;
            if (delay>20000)
                begin
                    delay<=0;
                    sram_state<=0;
                    mydata<=s_read_data;
                end
        end
        
end
```

I'm using the internal oscillator just for testing; around a 20MHz clock, but the timing seems well within the allowable timings. I've checked the IP express generated block and that seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using osc_clck in one place and osc_clk in another. Beware that by default, Verilog automatically creates undefined signals - this will usually produce a warning, but you can make it into an error with "`default_nettype none"